# I am trying to deploy my portfolio using heroku but kept getting an application error with code h10

Tags: web, heroku

I am trying to deploy my portfolio using Heroku and the web only has an HTML file, a CSS file, and a simple javaScript file. [screenshot of all my files are here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w85zv.png)

I pushed all of these files to Github and linked them to Heroku. Heroku deployed successfully but as I opened the URL, it gives me an application error with code H10. I googled a lot of fixes and tried adding a Procfile file but none seems to have worked. Can Anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to know that heroku is not designed to post static websites. Nevertheless if you still would like to upload static website you need to organize your structure to somehow trick Heroku to see your files as an application.

Add composer.json root directory by adding {} inside, and index.php to the root directory,in index.php, add the following line: `<?php include_once("home.html"); ?>`, change your index.html to home.html. Push them to heroku, now it should work.

Comment: Is there any other services that can post static websites for free?

Comment: Actually yes, as far as i know there are few of them, for example Neocities.